# Вывод случайного отзыва

Tags: php

Нужно вывести случайный отзыв из БД mysql. Есть ковывода всех отзывов, как его подредактировать на один случайный отзыв?

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT `users`.login AS login,`reviews`.rdate AS rdate,`reviews`.rpost AS rpost FROM `reviews` JOIN `users` ON `users`.uid=`reviews`.ruid ORDER BY `reviews`.rdate DESC;";
$mysql_result = mysql_query ($query);
?>

<table id="reviews_table"> 
<?php
    $class_num = 2;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($mysql_result)) {
        $class_num = 3 - $class_num;
?>
<tr class="reviews_table_tr_<?php echo $class_num; ?>">
    <td width="120px">
        <span class="login"><?php echo $row["login"]; ?></span>
        <br />
        <span class="date"><?php echo date("d.m.y H:i",$row["rdate"]+3*3600); ?>        </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["rpost"]); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено своими силами. Изменённый код:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT `users`.login AS login,`reviews`.rdate AS rdate,`reviews`.rpost AS rpost FROM `reviews` JOIN `users` ON `users`.uid=`reviews`.ruid ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
$mysql_result = mysql_query ($query);
?>
```